# Firebase Storage security rules .matches(regex) not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I've been working on writing securities rules for my website and come across an issue.
When I attempt to do the regex "^[0-9].jpg" I get an error. The error says that there is an unexpected "');" in storage.rules on line 8. I've tried changing the regex to "/^[0-9].jpg/" but to no avail. The only regexes it seems to like are the ones I directly copy and past from the docs. As for the regex, I am try to match filenames for 0.jpg, 1.jpg etc but below 10 total files.

Any help is appreciated!

```js
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /photos/{uid}{
      match /profile_photos/{image} {
      allow read: if isUserIsAuth();
      allow write: if isUserIsAuth() && isUserOwner(uid) && 
      image.matches('^[0-9]\.jpg');
    
      
      }
  
      }
    }
  }


function isUserIsAuth(){
    return request.auth != null && 
  request.auth.token.email_verified || request.auth != null && 
  request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider == "anonymous"
}
function isUserOwner(userID){
    return request.auth.uid == userID
}
```

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this?

Comment: No I just checked each possible case. Really annoying though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your regular expression: `^[0-9]\.jpg` should instead be `^[0-9]\\.jpg`. You can see [in the Firebase example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#public) that to match any file ending in `.txt`, they are using the following regular expression: `.*\\.txt`.

This comes from the fact that in the CEL language, to represent a backslash, you must enter two of them (`\\`), not just one ([link to the CEL language specifications here](https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md#string-and-bytes-values)) and that the regular expression must have the dot escaped using a backslash. So in order for the regular expression to match a period `.`, the string representing the regular expression needs to be `\.`, so the code entered must be `\\.` (since `\\` is converted to `\`).